# Specific step in proof of connectivity of intervals of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

> Let $A$ be a an interval of real numbers. Suppose it is not connected.
> There exist non-empty, open subsets $B,C$ of $A$ such that $A=B\cup C$
> and $B\cap C=\emptyset$. Let $x\in B$, $y\in C$ and $x<y$. Then the
> set $B\cap[x,y]$ is non-empty and bounded; let $z$ denote its
> supremum. Clearly $z\leq y$. Suppose $z\in B$. Then necessarily $z< y$
> and **there is by assumption an interval $[z,z+h)$ contained in $[x,y]$
> and $B$...**

How can the existence of this $h$ be justified? i.e. how to pick $h$ so that $[z,z+h)\subset B\cap [x,y]$?

Comment: Use the fact that $B$ and $C$ has to be open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $B$ is open and $(x,y)$ are open, so is $B\cap (x,y)$. As $z$ is in this set, there's an open interval around it that is also in $B\cap (x,y)\subset B\cap [x,y]$. If $(z-h,z+h)$ is in there, then so is $[z,z+h)$.